# What is the way to tell highcharter which colors to use for a pie chart using R?

Tags: r, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart using this code:

```
require(highcharter)
hdf=data.frame(count=c(11,15,25),name=c('a','b','c'),color=c('green','red','yellow'))
hc=hchart(hdf,
          'pie',
          hcaes(x=name,y=count,color=color),
          name='Name')
hc
```

However, stangely the outcome is not what one would expect.

Without the color-attribute in `hcaes` I get

[image: pie chart without color attribute]

With the color-attribute I get

[image: pie chart with color attribute]

You can recognize the viridis colors

[image: first three viridis colors]

but it is definitely not `c('green','red','yellow')`. However, the colors `c('green','red','yellow')` actually do change something: If you use `color=c('red','green','yellow')` instead, you get

[image: pie chart with changed color]

The function `hc_add_series_labels_values` seems to be deprecated in my version: `highcharter_0.9.4`. What is now the way to go to achieve what I want, using a color column in my `data.frame` for custom colors of my plot?

Comment: try adding `colorByPoint = TRUE` to the `hchart()` call.

Comment: Unfortunately `hc=hchart(hdf,
          'pie',
          hcaes(x=name,y=count,color=color),
          colorByPoint=TRUE,
          name='Name')` still has the same result.

Comment: I think, from reading the highcharter vignettes, that you don't want the `color=color` line inside `hcaes()` - that's more for passing a grouping variable to use for colour selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explicitly inform colors, you could try the following.

In your data.frame, including `y` for the count, and keep the same `name` and `color`. Then, provide this data to `hc_add_series`.

```
library(highcharter)

hdf = data.frame(
  y = c(11, 15, 25),
  name = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  color = c('green', 'red', 'yellow')
)

highchart() |> 
  hc_chart(type = "pie") |> 
  hc_add_series(data = hdf)
```

**Plot**

[image: highcharter pie chart with defined colors]